# How can I redirect internet traffic from local to proxy server with ip tables (DEBIAN 6)

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, proxy, squid

So i made topology as shown in figure.

[image: Topology]

Router have 3 interfaces like this:

> eth0 to internet side (with ip *192.168.1.10/24* gateway *192.168.1.254/24*).
>
> eth1 to server-PC side (with ip *192.168.20.1/28*)
>
> eth2 to Client side (with ip *172.16.20.1/29*)

Server and client connected and get internet from router-pc. Server-pc uses a static ip (*192.168.20.2*), while the client gets an automatic ip from DHCP on router-pc

And i want to configure iptables on my Router-PC to redirect client's internet to Proxy server on my Server-PC. So client must using credential to access internet (i already configure authentication proxy on my squid and already configure proxy manually on client side).

The firewall i've running is:

> *iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 172.16.20.0/29 -j DNAT --to 192.168.20.2*

192.168.20.2 is my Server's ip address. So, can you help me to fix the configuration I have done, in order to according to what I want?

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I'm newbie on Networking. Please help me, i really apreciate your opinion/answer. Thanks.

Comment: As the proxy has to be configured manually anyway on the clients, why not simply configure 192.168.20.2 as the proxy for the clients? Sometimes the simple solution is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I already configure 192.168.20.2 as my proxy server address. But some domains that should be blocked, it is not blocked and can still open by client. What should i do?

Comment: Disable forwarding of outbound port 80 and 443 connections: `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT` (repeat for port 443).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Default policy is ACCEPT for all right? If all access through port 80 and 443 rejected, would not that mean local/client side can't access any web/url?

Comment: Not *all* access is denied, that's what the `-i eth2 -o eth0` is for: to limit the rejection to packets that want to travel directly from client network to internet. If they use the proxy as they should, then there's no problem.

Comment: Thanks you so much Wurtel. Thanks. Thanks.
I running that script on my Router-PC right? How about firewall configuration I have done? Use it or not?

Comment: That `PREROUTING` rule is not of much use, so not.

Comment: You're referring to a web proxy? Or a socks proxy? Or something else? For example, if the client tries to receive email from an Internet host (e.g. IMAP from Office365) what policy do you have for that? Deny? Allow?

Comment: @roaima: I refer to a squid which should work as a transparent proxy on "PC server" listening on port 3129.

Comment: There was an equivalent question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/490594/redirect-local-traffic-to-proxy-port-with-iptables 
and also here too https://superuser.com/questions/850710/how-to-forward-http-request-to-a-proxy-server

Answer (score 1):

First: please note that Debian 6 "squeeze" has been out of mainline support since 2013, and out of long term support since 2016. Using Debian 6 to prevent Internet access in this manner is very likely to be ineffective, due to security bugs that allow the restrictions to be bypassed, missing functionality that make you uncapable of implementing the requested rulesets, or both. I *strongly* recommend that you upgrade your system to a supported Debian release, preferably Debian 9 "stretch".

Second, combining authenticated proxies with transparent proxy mode doesn't work all that well. The problem is that the end host might *also* require authentication (e.g., because you're logging in to a DAV server which requires HTTP-level authentication), and then your transparent proxy is either going to eat those credentials, or be confused about them.

Instead, what I suggest is the following:

- Block all traffic that doesn't go over the proxy:

  ```
  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
  ```

  This disallows all Internet traffic that doesn't go over the proxy.
- Configure your DHCP server so it sends a domain name to clients:

  ```
  subnet 172.16.20.1/29 {
      (...)
      option domain-name "example.com";
  };
  ```

  (use your local domain name, not `example.com` here)
- Configure your DNS server so it knows the hostname `wpad.example.com`, which should point to your router (again, substitute `example.com` for your domain name).
- Create a file wpad.dat, and give it the following contents:

  ```
  function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
      return "PROXY 172.16.20.1:3128";
  }
  ```

  Note that this is simple Javascript; if you want to use a different proxy depending on the destination URL, just modify the function.

  Then serve that file over HTTP on the router, with the name "/wpad.dat". Make sure the MIME type for that file is either `application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig` or `application/x-javascript-config`.

With that, browsers on your network will be automatically configured to use the proxy (provided you have the "Automatically detect settings" option switched on, where relevant), and will not confuse your users regarding authentication.